# Did the Mac OS X Java update to 1.5u7 whack my 1.6.0 laf.jar?

Tags: macos, jvm

This is the update that just came out this week (2010-05-18).
Somebody moved my cheese.  It appears that laf.jar is look and feel, so it is probably not a big deal for my Java development.  Eclipse got mad about the missing JAR file, and furthermore thinks the 1.6.0 VM disappeared, which it didn't. I had to redefine the VM library within Eclipse and everything appears kosher, but I was hoping somebody with more hit points than me could say so definitively.  Am I all good?  Was it really the Mac OS X update for 1.5 that went and hunted down a file in my 1.6 VM?

I haven't been able to google anything about this... If somebody could post a link to some information about this, that'd be appreciated too.

Comment: Could you explain what you did to stop eclipse complaining? I have the same problem.

Comment: theLokh's answer below will get you sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Eclipse complained that there were classes missing in laf.jar. I've done basically the same thing: I went to *Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs* . When I clicked on it Eclipse told me that it could not find the JVM 1.6 at the specified path and removed it. I then told Eclipse to search for existing JVMs. It found (of course) 1.6. The error in laf.jar disappeared and Eclipse did not complain anymore.

Comment: Weirdness indeed. Same thing just happened to me. However, all I had to do was restart Eclipse and everything is working fine again